# Using temporary y Using Filesort MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo un problema con una consulta y es que necesito verificar dos tablas, una con 26 millones de datos (`cmmovimiento_ventas`) y otra con 65mil datos (`items). Sucede que para dicha consulta debo realizar una suma en 3 campos diferentes la cual debo agrupar por ciertos campos para que me arroje los valores exactos, pero, cuando utilizo el "explain" para verificar cómo está actuando la consulta, observo el "Using temporary" y el "using filesoft". Desearía saber si hay alguna forma de poder evitar este paso extra, no sé si tenga algo malo en mi consulta o si es algo que no se pueda evitar. Anexo aquí la consulta y el explain:

```
SELECT
    mv.LAPSO_DOC AS LAPSO,
    (
        SELECT
            LINEAS.ID_LINEA
        FROM
            LINEAS
        WHERE
            (LINEAS.ID_TIPO = '1')
            AND (LINEAS.ID_LINEA = SUBSTR(itm.ID_LINEA,1,2))
    ) AS LINEA_NV1,
    (
        SELECT
            LINEAS.CMLINEAS_DESCRIPCION
        FROM
            LINEAS
        WHERE
            (LINEAS.ID_TIPO='1')
            AND LINEAS.ID_LINEA = SUBSTR(itm.ID_LINEA,1,2)
    ) AS DESCRIPCION_NV1,
    (
        SELECT
            LINEAS.ID_LINEA
        FROM
            LINEAS
        WHERE
            (LINEAS.ID_TIPO = '1')
            AND (LINEAS.ID_LINEA = SUBSTR(itm.ID_LINEA,1,4))
    ) AS LINEA_NV2,
    (
        SELECT
            LINEAS.CMLINEAS_DESCRIPCION
        FROM
            LINEAS
        WHERE
            (LINEAS.ID_TIPO='1')
            AND LINEAS.ID_LINEA = SUBSTR(itm.ID_LINEA,1,4)
    ) AS DESCRIPCION_NV2,
    (
        SELECT
            LINEAS.ID_LINEA
        FROM
            LINEAS
        WHERE
            (LINEAS.ID_TIPO = '1')
            AND (LINEAS.ID_LINEA = SUBSTR(itm.ID_LINEA,1,6))
    ) AS LINEA_NV3,
    (
        SELECT
            LINEAS.CMLINEAS_DESCRIPCION
        FROM
            LINEAS
        WHERE
            (LINEAS.ID_TIPO='1')
            AND LINEAS.ID_LINEA = SUBSTR(itm.ID_LINEA, 1, 6)
    ) AS DESCRIPCION_NV3,
    itm.ID_ITEM AS COD_ITEM,
    itm.DESCRIPCION AS DESCRIPCION,
    CONCAT('SEDE', ' ', mv.ID_CO) AS CENTRO_OPERACION,
    (
        SELECT
            ct1.ID_CRICLA1
        FROM
            CRITERIOS_ITM_1 ct1
        WHERE
            ct1.ID_CRICLA1 = itm.ID_CRICLA1
            AND itm.ID_TIPO = '1'
    ) AS CRITERIO_ITEM1,
    (
        SELECT
            ct1.CMCRICLA_DESCRIPCION
        FROM
            CRITERIOS_ITM_1 ct1
        WHERE
            ct1.ID_CRICLA1 = itm.ID_CRICLA1
            AND itm.ID_TIPO = '1'
    ) AS NOMBRE_CRITERIO1,
    SUM(TOT_BRUTO) AS VALOR_NETO,
    SUM(RENTABIL) AS RENTABILIDAD,
    SUM(CANTIDAD) AS CANTIDAD
FROM
    CMMOVIMIENTO_VENTAS mv 
    INNER JOIN  ITEMS itm ON
        mv.ID_ITEM = itm.ID_ITEM
WHERE
    itm.ID_TIPO = "1"
    AND itm.ESTADO = "0"
    AND SUBSTR(mv.LAPSO_DOC,1,4) BETWEEN 2016 AND 2017
    AND SUBSTR(mv.LAPSO_DOC,5,6) BETWEEN 01 AND 03
    AND itm.ID_EXT_ITM = mv.`ID_EXT_ITM`
GROUP BY
    itm.DESCRIPCION
ORDER BY
    itm.ID_ITEM ASC
```

Edito la pregunta con los resultados del EXPLAIN y el SHOW WARNINGS (No tuvo ningún resultado) a petición de Xint0. Aquí están los resultados

**Edición con el EXPLAIN de la consulta actual.**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo al resultado de `EXPLAIN` que se incluye, el índice que está utilizando para filtrar los registros de la tabla `ITEMS` no es el óptimo, ya que me atrevo a decir que no incluye el campo con el cuál se hace la intersección con los registros de la tabla `CMMOVIMIENTO_VENTAS`.

Por el nombre del índice `TIPINV_ix` me atrevo a deducir que solo incluye la columna `ID_TIPO`, de ahí que filtre los registros con el valor `ID_TIPO = 1`, luego los ponga en una tabla temporal y debido al espacio que consumen, tenga que utilizar espacio en disco para ordenarlos por las otras columnas que se utilizan en el filtrado y la intersección (`ESTADO`, `ID_ITEM`, `ID_EXT_ITM`).

La consulta se vería beneficiada por un índice en la tabla `ITEMS` que incluya las columnas: `(ID_TIPO, ESTADO, ID_ITEM, ID_EXT_ITM)`.

Para optimizar el filtrado e intersección con la tabla `CMMOVIMIENTO_VENTAS` te recomiendo tener un índice que incluya las columnas: `(LAPSO_DOC, ID_ITEM, ID_EXT_ITM)` y cambiar las condiciones:

```
AND SUBSTR(mv.LAPSO_DOC,1,4) BETWEEN 2016 AND 2017
AND SUBSTR(mv.LAPSO_DOC,5,6) BETWEEN 01 AND 03
```

Para que puedan utilizar dicho índice, ya que al tener una función no utiliza el índice y se tiene que hacer un recorrido sobre los registros.  Pudiera cambiarse a algo como:

```
AND ((mv.LAPSO_DOC >= '20160101' AND mv.LAPSO_DOC < '20160401')
    OR (mv.LAPSO_DOC >= '20170101' AND mv.LAPSO_DOC < '20170401'))
```

Asumiendo que `LAPSO_DOC` es una cadena de caracteres que representa una fecha y solo se quieren incluir los primeros tres meses de los años 2016 y 2017.

Dado que se tiene un `OR` entonces, la recomendación es aplicar la unión de dos consultas con el operador `UNION`.

Por otro lado, en lugar de utilizar sub-consultas en la selección de campos, te sugiero utilizar intersecciones con tablas derivadas, es decir pasar las subconsultas a la cláusula `FROM`.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

La consulta sugerida es:

```
SELECT
    t.LAPSO_DOC,
    l1.ID_LINEA AS LINEA_NV1,
    l1.DESCRIPCION AS DESCRIPCION_NV1,
    l2.ID_LINEA AS LINEA_NV2,
    l2.DESCRIPCION AS DEsCRIPCION_NV2,
    l3.ID_LINEA AS LINEA_NV3,
    l3.DESCRIPCION AS DESCRIPCION_NV3,
    t.ID_ITEM AS COD_ITEM,
    i.DESCRIPCION,
    CONCAT('SEDE', ' ', t.ID_CO) AS CENTRO_OPERACION,
    c.ID_CRICLA1 AS CRITERIO_ITEM1,
    c.CMCRCLICA_DESCRIPCION AS NOMBRE_CRITERIO1,
    t.VALOR_NETO,
    t.RENTABILIDAD,
    t.CANTIDAD
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            mv.LAPSO_DOC,
            mv.ID_CO,
            mv.ID_LINEA,
            mv.ID_CRICLA1,
            mv.ID_ITEM,
            SUM(mv.TOT_BRUTO) AS VALOR_NETO,
            SUM(mv.RENTABIL) AS RENTABILIDAD,
            SUM(mv.CANTIDAD) AS CANTIDAD
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    m1.LAPSO_DOC,
                    m1.ID_CO,
                    i.ID_LINEA,
                    i.ID_CRICLA1,
                    m1.ID_ITEM,
                    m1.TOT_BRUTO,
                    m1.RENTABIL,
                    m1.CANTIDAD
                FROM
                    CMMOVIMIENTO_VENTAS m1
                    INNER JOIN ITEMS i ON
                    i.ID_ITEM = m1.ID_ITEM
                    AND i.ID_TIPO = "1"
                    AND i.ESTADO = "0"
                    AND m1.LAPSO_DOC BETWEEN "201601" AND "201603"
                UNION ALL
                SELECT
                    m2.LAPSO_DOC,
                    m2.ID_CO,
                    i.ID_LINEA,
                    i.ID_CRICLA1,
                    m2.ID_ITEM,
                    m2.TOT_BRUTO,
                    m2.RENTABIL,
                    m2.CANTIDAD
                FROM
                    CMMOVIMIENTO_VENTAS m2
                    INNER JOIN ITEMS i ON
                        i.ID_ITEM = m2.ID_ITEM
                        AND i.ID_TIPO = "1"
                        AND i.ESTADO = "0"
                        AND m2.LAPSO_DOC BETWEEN "201701" AND "201703"
            ) mv
        GROUP BY
            mv.LAPSO_DOC,
            mv.ID_CO,
            mv.ID_LINEA,
            mv.ID_CRICLA1,
            mv.ID_ITEM,
    ) t
    INNER JOIN LINEAS AS l1 ON
        l1.ID_LINEA = SUBSTR(t.ID_LINEA, 1, 2)
        AND l1.ID_TIPO = "1"
    INNER JOIN LINEAS AS l2 ON
        l2.ID_LINEA = SUBSTR(t.ID_LINEA, 1, 4)
        AND l2.ID_TIPO = "2"
    INNER JOIN LINEAS AS l3 ON
        l3.ID_LINEA = SUBSTR(t.ID_LINEA, 1, 6)
        AND l3.ID_TIPO = "3"
    INNER JOIN CRITERIOS_ITM_1 AS c ON
        c.ID_CRICLA1 = t.ID_CRICLA1
    INNER JOIN ITEMS AS i ON
        i.ID_ITEM = t.ID_ITEM;
```

Y los índices sugeridos son:

```
CREATE INDEX IX1ITEMS ON ITEMS (ID_TIPO, ID_ESTADO, ID_CRICLA1, ID_LINEA, ID_ITEM);
CREATE INDEX IX1CMMOVIMIENTO_VENTAS ON CMMOVIMIENTO_VENTAS (LAPSO_DOC, ID_ITEM);
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN 2**

Después de analizar el plan de ejecución, me parece que no está utilizando el índice sugerido en la tabla `CMMOVIMIENTO_VENTAS`, por lo que sugiero cambiar su definción a:

```
CREATE INDEX IX1CMMOVIMIENTO_VENTAS ON CMMOVIMIENTO_VENTAS (ID_ITEM, LAPSO_DOC);
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN 3**

Dado que en la sumarización se está agrupando por los campos `LAPSO_DOC`, `ID_CO`, `ID_LINEA`, `ID_CRICLA1`, y `ID_ITEM`, entonces podemos hacer dicha sumarización *antes* de la unión:

```
SELECT
    t.LAPSO_DOC,
    l1.ID_LINEA AS LINEA_NV1,
    l1.DESCRIPCION AS DESCRIPCION_NV1,
    l2.ID_LINEA AS LINEA_NV2,
    l2.DESCRIPCION AS DEsCRIPCION_NV2,
    l3.ID_LINEA AS LINEA_NV3,
    l3.DESCRIPCION AS DESCRIPCION_NV3,
    t.ID_ITEM AS COD_ITEM,
    i.DESCRIPCION,
    CONCAT('SEDE', ' ', t.ID_CO) AS CENTRO_OPERACION,
    c.ID_CRICLA1 AS CRITERIO_ITEM1,
    c.CMCRCLICA_DESCRIPCION AS NOMBRE_CRITERIO1,
    t.VALOR_NETO,
    t.RENTABILIDAD,
    t.CANTIDAD
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            m1.LAPSO_DOC,
            m1.ID_CO,
            i.ID_LINEA,
            i.ID_CRICLA1,
            m1.ID_ITEM,
            SUM(m1.TOT_BRUTO) AS VALOR_NETO,
            SUM(m1.RENTABIL) AS RENTABILIDAD,
            SUM(m1.CANTIDAD) AS CANTIDAD
        FROM
            CMMOVIMIENTO_VENTAS m1
            INNER JOIN ITEMS i ON
                i.ID_ITEM = m1.ID_ITEM
                AND i.ID_TIPO = "1"
                AND i.ESTADO = "0"
                AND m1.LAPSO_DOC BETWEEN "201601" AND "201603"
        GROUP BY
            m1.LAPSO_DOC,
            m1.ID_CO,
            i.ID_LINEA,
            i.ID_CRICLA1,
            m1.ID_ITEM
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            m2.LAPSO_DOC,
            m2.ID_CO,
            i.ID_LINEA,
            i.ID_CRICLA1,
            m2.ID_ITEM,
            SUM(m2.TOT_BRUTO),
            SUM(m2.RENTABIL),
            SUM(m2.CANTIDAD)
        FROM
            CMMOVIMIENTO_VENTAS m2
            INNER JOIN ITEMS i ON
                i.ID_ITEM = m2.ID_ITEM
                AND i.ID_TIPO = "1"
                AND i.ESTADO = "0"
                AND m2.LAPSO_DOC BETWEEN "201701" AND "201703"
        GROUP BY
            m2.LAPSO_DOC,
            m2.ID_CO,
            i.ID_LINEA,
            i.ID_CRICLA1,
            m2.ID_ITEM
    ) t
    INNER JOIN LINEAS AS l1 ON
        l1.ID_LINEA = SUBSTR(t.ID_LINEA, 1, 2)
        AND l1.ID_TIPO = "1"
    INNER JOIN LINEAS AS l2 ON
        l2.ID_LINEA = SUBSTR(t.ID_LINEA, 1, 4)
        AND l2.ID_TIPO = "2"
    INNER JOIN LINEAS AS l3 ON
        l3.ID_LINEA = SUBSTR(t.ID_LINEA, 1, 6)
        AND l3.ID_TIPO = "3"
    INNER JOIN CRITERIOS_ITM_1 AS c ON
        c.ID_CRICLA1 = t.ID_CRICLA1
    INNER JOIN ITEMS AS i ON
        i.ID_ITEM = t.ID_ITEM;
```

**Actualización 4**

Del último `EXPLAIN` veo que no está aprovechando el índice sugerido `IX1ITEMS`, quizás se deba a la cantidad de índices en la tabla `ITEMS` por lo que mi sugerencia es eliminar índices.  Realmente me parece que son demasiados 45 índices en una tabla.

Por otra parte, si se mueven los `INNER JOIN` para hacerlos antes de la unión debe mejorar más la consulta:

```
SELECT
    m1.LAPSO_DOC,
    l1.ID_LINEA AS LINEA_NV1,
    l1.DESCRIPCION AS DESCRIPCION_NV1,
    l2.ID_LINEA AS LINEA_NV2,
    l2.DESCRIPCION AS DEsCRIPCION_NV2,
    l3.ID_LINEA AS LINEA_NV3,
    l3.DESCRIPCION AS DESCRIPCION_NV3,
    m1.ID_ITEM AS COD_ITEM,
    i.DESCRIPCION,
    CONCAT('SEDE', ' ', t.ID_CO) AS CENTRO_OPERACION,
    i.ID_CRICLA1 AS CRITERIO_ITEM,
    c.CMCRCLICA_DESCRIPCION AS NOMBRE_CRITERIO1,
    SUM(m1.TOT_BRUTO) AS VALOR_NETO,
    SUM(m1.RENTABIL) AS RENTABILIDAD,
    SUM(m1.CANTIDAD) AS CANTIDAD
FROM
    CMMOVIMIENTO_VENTAS m1
    INNER JOIN ITEMS i ON
        i.ID_ITEM = m1.ID_ITEM
        AND i.ID_TIPO = "1"
        AND i.ESTADO = "0"
        AND m1.LAPSO_DOC BETWEEN "201601" AND "201603"
    INNER JOIN LINEAS AS l1 ON
        l1.ID_LINEA = SUBSTR(i.ID_LINEA, 1, 2)
        AND l1.ID_TIPO = "1"
    INNER JOIN LINEAS AS l2 ON
        l2.ID_LINEA = SUBSTR(i.ID_LINEA, 1, 4)
        AND l2.ID_TIPO = "2"
    INNER JOIN LINEAS AS l3 ON
        l3.ID_LINEA = SUBSTR(i.ID_LINEA, 1, 6)
        AND l3.ID_TIPO = "3"
    INNER JOIN CRITERIOS_ITM_1 AS c ON
        c.ID_CRICLA1 = i.ID_CRICLA1
GROUP BY
    m1.LAPSO_DOC,
    l1.ID_LINEA,
    l1.DESCRIPCION,
    l2.ID_LINEA,
    l2.DESCRIPCION,
    l3.ID_LINEA,
    l3.DESCRIPCION,
    m1.ID_ITEM,
    i.DESCRIPCION,
    CONCAT('SEDE', ' ', t.ID_CO),
    i.ID_CRICLA1,
    c.CMCRCLICA_DESCRIPCION
UNION ALL
SELECT
    m2.LAPSO_DOC,
    l1.ID_LINEA AS LINEA_NV1,
    l1.DESCRIPCION AS DESCRIPCION_NV1,
    l2.ID_LINEA AS LINEA_NV2,
    l2.DESCRIPCION AS DEsCRIPCION_NV2,
    l3.ID_LINEA AS LINEA_NV3,
    l3.DESCRIPCION AS DESCRIPCION_NV3,
    m2.ID_ITEM AS COD_ITEM,
    i.DESCRIPCION,
    CONCAT('SEDE', ' ', t.ID_CO) AS CENTRO_OPERACION,
    i.ID_CRICLA1 AS CRITERIO_ITEM,
    c.CMCRCLICA_DESCRIPCION AS NOMBRE_CRITERIO1,
    SUM(m2.TOT_BRUTO),
    SUM(m2.RENTABIL),
    SUM(m2.CANTIDAD)
FROM
    CMMOVIMIENTO_VENTAS m2
    INNER JOIN ITEMS i ON
        i.ID_ITEM = m2.ID_ITEM
        AND i.ID_TIPO = "1"
        AND i.ESTADO = "0"
        AND m2.LAPSO_DOC BETWEEN "201701" AND "201703"
    INNER JOIN LINEAS AS l1 ON
        l1.ID_LINEA = SUBSTR(i.ID_LINEA, 1, 2)
        AND l1.ID_TIPO = "1"
    INNER JOIN LINEAS AS l2 ON
        l2.ID_LINEA = SUBSTR(i.ID_LINEA, 1, 4)
        AND l2.ID_TIPO = "2"
    INNER JOIN LINEAS AS l3 ON
        l3.ID_LINEA = SUBSTR(i.ID_LINEA, 1, 6)
        AND l3.ID_TIPO = "3"
    INNER JOIN CRITERIOS_ITM_1 AS c ON
        c.ID_CRICLA1 = i.ID_CRICLA1
GROUP BY
    m2.LAPSO_DOC,
    l1.ID_LINEA,
    l1.DESCRIPCION,
    l2.ID_LINEA,
    l2.DESCRIPCION,
    l3.ID_LINEA,
    l3.DESCRIPCION,
    m2.ID_ITEM,
    i.DESCRIPCION,
    CONCAT('SEDE', ' ', t.ID_CO),
    i.ID_CRICLA1,
    c.CMCRCLICA_DESCRIPCION;
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58860/discussion-on-answer-by-xint0-using-temporary-y-using-filesort-mysql).

Answer (score 0):

### A. Using temporary

[La documentación de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/internal-temporary-tables.html) indica las posibles causas para que aparezca `Using temporary`.

#### Uso de tabla temporal interna en MySQL

En algunos casos, el servidor crea tablas temporales internas mientras procesa las sentencias. Los usuarios no tienen control directo sobre cuándo ocurre esto.

El servidor crea tablas temporales bajo condiciones como estas:

- Evaluación de las declaraciones de UNION, con algunas excepciones descritas más adelante.
- Evaluación de algunas vistas, como aquellas que usan el algoritmo TEMPTABLE, UNIÓN o agregación.
- Evaluación de tablas derivadas (subconsultas en la cláusula FROM).
- Tablas creadas para la materialización de subconsulta o semiunión ([consulte la Sección 9.2.2, "Optimización de subconsultas, tablas derivadas y referencias de vistas"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subquery-optimization.html)).
- Evaluación de sentencias que contienen una cláusula ORDER BY y otra cláusula GROUP BY o para las que ORDER BY o GROUP BY contienen columnas de tablas que no sean la primera tabla de la cola de ensamblaje.
- La evaluación de DISTINCT combinada con ORDER BY puede requerir una tabla temporal.
- Para las consultas que utilizan el modificador SQL_SMALL_RESULT, MySQL utiliza una tabla temporal en memoria, a menos que la consulta también contenga elementos (descritos más adelante) que requieran almacenamiento en disco.
- Evaluación de sentencias UPDATE de varias tablas.
- Evaluación de expresiones GROUP_CONCAT () o COUNT (DISTINCT).

Hay más, en la documentación (en inglés).

### B. using filesort

Aquí [How MySQL executes ORDER BY](http://s.petrunia.net/blog/?p=24), hay una excelente explicación de `filesort` (¿lo habrás escrito mal?).

Esta parte está tomada de dicho artículo, si vas directamente a él encontrarás más información.

MySQL tiene dos métodos para producir flujos ordenados.

El primero es utilizar un método de acceso "rango", "ref" o "índice" sobre un índice ordenado. Para versiones de hasta 5.1, esos métodos de acceso devuelven naturalmente registros en el orden de índice, por lo que obtendremos pedidos de forma gratuita (la excepción es el motor NDB que necesita hacer merge-sort cuando obtiene datos de varios nodos de almacenamiento). En MySQL 5.2, MyISAM e InnoDB tienen optimización de MultiRangeRead que rompe el orden. Tenemos un borrador de cómo hacer que preserve el pedido, pero por el momento MRR simplemente se inhabilita cuando se requiere el pedido.

El segundo, método catch-all, es utilizar el algoritmo `filesort`. En pocas palabras, filesort () hace quicksort en trozos de datos que se ajustan a su memoria y luego utiliza el enfoque mergesort para combinar los trozos. La cantidad de memoria disponible para filesort () es controlada por @@ sort_buffer_size variable. Si los datos ordenados no encajan en la memoria (es decir, hay más de un fragmento), filesort utiliza un archivo temporal para almacenar los fragmentos.

Los datos de origen para filesort () siempre provienen de una tabla. Si hay una necesidad de ordenar los datos de varias tablas, MySQL primero recogerá los datos en una tabla temporal y luego invocará filesort () para esa tabla temporal. No sé la verdadera razón de esto. Codewise, filesort () quiere extraer sus datos de origen utilizando algo como la función source.get_next_record (), mientras que el tiempo de ejecución union y union producen sus llamadas result.put_put_next_record () - tipo, así que tal vez la tabla temporal está allí sólo para resolver este empuje / Pull no coinciden y desaparecerá una vez que obtengamos cursores decentes.

Filesort () tiene dos modos de operación:

Modo 1: los elementos ordenados contienen todas las columnas necesarias de la tabla de origen. El resultado de la ordenación es una secuencia lineal de tuplas de salida, no hay necesidad de acceder a la tabla de origen después de la ordenación.

Modo 2: ordenar  pares y producir una secuencia de rowids que se puede utilizar para obtener las filas de la tabla de origen en el orden requerido (pero esto será básicamente golpear la tabla en orden aleatorio y no es muy rápido).

---

### EDIT

Creo que en tu caso hay que hacer una evaluación por el camino correcto, hay que ir en busca del problema empezando por la superficie y seguir profundizando hasta niveles más delicados.

Me explico:

Si tienes una consulta que se revela *lenta*, no te vayas directamente a cambiar cosas en la base de datos tales como índices de tablas. Primero porque en una tabla con muchos millones de registros el cambio de índices podría tardar horas en hacerse efectivo y si la BD es consultada constantemente, el costo va a ser importante; segundo porque si ese índice no resuelve el problema tendrías que volver a cambiar los índices y la BD tendría que volver a reindexarse...

Entonces, *evaluar desde la superficia hacia el fondo* significa que empieces por analizar tu consulta, viendo lo que se puede optimizar en ella, a veces el problema está ahí. Por ejemplo en este caso, **¿por qué no se usa JOIN para unir las tablas?**.

A veces, por una tontería, algo que se ha escapado, como colocar un `JOIN` cuando se necesitaba un `LEFT JOIN` hace una consulta lentísima... eso requiere un análisis serio de tu sentencia SQL.

A veces el problema es un índice en alguna de las tablas menores que hace que se carguen datos a mansalva de esa tabla menor, porque el índice está mal en ella, por ejemplo un mal índice en la tabla `paises`.

Es un tema delicado, dada la gran cantidad de datos que están en juego.

[En esta respuesta a un problema similar al tuyo se dan una serie de criterios que me parecen interesantes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/54214). No es una respuesta aceptada, pero eso no significa que sea mala. Por ejemplo, se sugiere, en caso de que el problema no sea la consulta, sino los índices de la tabla, de crear una tabla temporal, replicando datos de la tabla real, cambiar los índices en dicha tabla temporal y hacer pruebas... me parece una solución inteligente. En la respuesta se dan también otros pasos a seguir que podrían serte de utilidad.

[Este artículo también es interesante](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/alterhuge), tratando de lo mismo.

Creo que ahí tienes datos para analizar lo que está ocurriendo. También [puedes consultar este caso en enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13633406/5587982).

Se trata de encontrar el problema, tratando en lo menos posible de alterar los datos, a menos que no quede otra salida.

Comment: Leí un poco e intente organizar un poco más mi consulta, pero, aun así el filesort (Sí jaja, lo escribí mal. No me fije) y el temporary siguen apareciendo. En el group by probe colocando campos de la primer tabla CMMOVIMIENTO_VENTAS e igual sigue causando firesort y temporary. Se me olvidó agregar que dicha relación de ambas tablas está hecha por indice más no por primary key

Comment: @Salth95 Tratándose de una base de datos con tantos registros, se requiere mucha cautela a la hora de entrar a cambiar cualquier cosa a nivel de las tablas. Una tabla con millones de registros, si le cambias un índice, podría tardar horas en hacerlo efectivo. Editaré la pregunta colocando algo sobre eso. En tablas pequeñas he notado que cuando cambias algo, no tiene efecto inmediato y que muchas veces hay que limpiar la caché.

Comment: gracias por responder!. Realmente es un problema tomando en cuenta que sólo en mi tabla de ITEMS existen 45 Indices y en la tabla CMMOVIMIENTO_VENTAS existen 19. Por las respuestas me he guiado un poco más y estoy tratando de verificar que cambios podrían resultar beneficiosos trabajando en una base de datos test que tengo en phpmyadmin.